# Shape 1 of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]])
v = np.array([1, 0, 1])
```

In Python's view, `x` has shape (4, 3) and `v` shape (3, ). Why didn't Python view `v` as having shape (, 3). Also, why do `v` and `v.T` have the same shape (3, ). IMHO, I think if `v` has shape (3, ) then `v.T` should have shape (, 3)?

Comment: There are two issues - the proper notation for a tuple (`shape` is a `tuple`), and what does it mean to be 1 dimensional.  People coming from MATLAB, and some linear algebra, backgrounds, can't conceive of an array that only has 1 dimension.  It has to be a row vector or column vector, never a plain vector. :)

Comment: This does give it another dimension that I didn't think of. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`(3,)` does not mean the `3` is first. It is simply the Python way of writing a 1-element tuple. If the shape were a list instead, it would be `[3]`.

`(, 3)` is not valid Python. The syntax for a 1-element tuple is `(element,)`.

The reason it can't be just `(3)` is that Python simply views the parentheses as a grouping construct, meaning `(3)` is interpreted as `3`, an integer.

Comment: Thanks, Tomothy. But why doesn't Python display the element of an array along with its dimension? I mean if it shows ```x.shape``` as (4, 3), it would be more intuitive/consistent to show ```v.shape``` as (1, 3) and ```v.T.shape``` as (3, 1)?

Comment: @Jason Because `v` is one dimensional, meaning `len(v.shape)` should be nothing else other than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, numpy arrays are n-dimensional. The shape tells dimensions in the order. If it is 1-D you will see only 1st dimension, 2-D only 2 dimensions and so on.

Here x is a 2-D array while v is a 1-D array (aka vector). That is why when you do shape on v you see (3,) meaning it has only one dimension whereas x.shape gives (4,3). When you transpose v, then that is also a 1-D array. To understand this better, try another example. Create a 3-D array.

```
z=np.ones((5,6,7))
z.shape
print (z)
```

Comment: Thanks, RebornCodeLover. I almost accepted your response as the answer but I wonder why Python's syntax doesn't allow the ```v.T.shape``` as (, 3) which both conform to ```v.T``` as one dimension and make distinction between ```v``` and ```v.T```. Although Tomothy explained the syntax is (elements, ) but why can't it be (, elments)?

Comment: Whether it is v or v.T, it is exactly the same 1-D array. Try print(v) and print(v.T). But if you do on the 2-D array, you would see the rows and columns switched.

Comment: Yes I do realise that ```v``` and ```v.T``` are both 1-D. But my wish was that Python should have shape (3, ) and (, 3) respectively to make things more intuitive!